# React: can you use setState with existing state object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Lets say I have a React component that has a "state" with 10 fields:

```
this.state = {
    field1: 1,
    field2: 2,
    ... other fields
    something: 'a'
};
```

In one of my event handlers, I decide I want to update a single state field. Is it for some reason bad practice to do it like this?

```
// state has 10 other properties not touched here, and I want them to
// retain their existing values
this.state.something = 'b';
this.setState(this.state);
```

Or must I do:

```
this.setState({
    field1: this.state.field1,
    field2: this.state.field2,
    ... set other fields with current value
    something: 'b'
});
```

I'm aware there are libraries that make it easy to copy object state, just wondered if it is necessary to do that. I should also add that I have tried this and it seems to work, but I haven't seen any examples online do this so wondered if there is some reason why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

use `Object.assign` for clone object

```
const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
  something: 'b'
})

this.setState(newState)
```

Or you can merge current state:

```
this.setState({
  something: 'a',
  something2: 'b', 
})
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I am looking for. Must of missed it when I skimmed over the docs.

Comment: if you missed this information you can read this here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Comment: Does your two examples have different effects? In terms of re-rendering?

Answer (score 5):

To update single field you need to pass object with this field. React will merge it for you.

```
this.setState({something: 'b'})
```

Comment: Say I wanted to update 3 of 10 fields, would that also work and be merged for me?

Comment: Sure. `{field1: 1, field2: 2 ...}`

Comment: Will work, but will result in a compiler error unless the `State` is declared properly.

Answer (score 4):

You would actually mark all the members of `State` as optional.

```
interface State {
  field1?: number, 
  field2?: number,
}
```

This is not as unsafe as you might think. TypeScript added the concept of **freshness** to support this pattern and others.

## More

This is covered here :

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/freshness.html#use-case--react-state