# React state updating without setState

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add items to a cart and I have set a condition to setState only when the quantity `items.quantity` in stock is greater than or equal to the quantity being added `items.qty` but it seems to ignore the condition and even the setState call.

```
constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: [

      ],
      x: 1,
      inventory: [
        {id: 0,name: "item 1",amount: 100.00, quantity: 1},
        {id: 1,name: "item 2",amount: 400.00, quantity: 2}
      ]
    }
  }  
addItem = (i) =>{
    const {items} = this.state;
    var id = this.state.inventory[i].id;
    items[id] = this.state.inventory[i];
    items[id].qty = items[id].hasOwnProperty('qty') ? items[id].qty+1 : 1;
    console.log(items[id].quantity>=items[id].qty);
    if(items[id].quantity>=items[id].qty){
      this.setState({
        items: items
      })
    }
    console.log(items);
    console.log(this.state.items[id].qty);
  }
```

and the List somewhere...

```
const ItemList = ({ inventory,addItem }) =>
  <List style={styles.List}>
  {
    inventory.map((item) =>
    <ListItem key={item.id} primaryText={item.name}
    secondaryText={item.amount}
    rightIcon={<ActionInfo />}
    onClick={addItem.bind(this,item.id)} />)
  }
  </List>
```

...After a frustrating weekend finally got it to work, even though I still don't fully understand why the state object would change. I guess more reading to do.

**Solution**

```
addItem=(i)=>{
    let items = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.items));
    let id = this.state.inventory[i].id;
    if(!items[id])
      items.push(this.state.inventory[i]);
    items[id].qty = items[id].hasOwnProperty('qty') ? items[id].qty+1 : 1;
    if(items[id].quantity>=items[id].qty){
      this.setState({items: items})
    }
  }
```

Comment: Start to use immutable data structures. Don't change the original object. Create a new object with changed properties.

Comment: Could you show me what that looks like. Cause I'm not sure I understand. Isn't the items array I declare not the same as the state array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Items is an array, you could do

```
let newItems = this.state.items.slice();
```

This will create a new array, but keep in mind it's contents don't get cloned.. but I think that is ok for this use case.

```js
let array1 = [{foo: 'bar'}];
let array2 = array1.slice();
array2.push({foo: 'new'});

// array 1 not affected
console.log(array1);

array1[0].foo = 'changed';
// array2 affected
console.log(array2);
```

If you ever need a true deep clone you can use [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/) or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObj))`.

Comment: I think it will need a clone of `this.state.inventory[i]` or at least a refactor of the method because it is currently changing the state directly.

Answer (score -1):

How to fix them:

```
const items = { ...this.state.items};
```

Possible duplicate: [React: can you use setState with existing state object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528444/react-can-you-use-setstate-with-existing-state-object)

Comment: This won't actually help because `items[id].qty` will still change `this.state`.