# React setState automatically with standard Javascript function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state

newb on ReactJS, let's look at some code I am using

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
import Oak from './Oak'
class Space extends Component {
  componentWillMount () {  Newstate = Oak(oldState) }
  componentWillUpdate () { }

  render () {
    return()
  }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) { return {bigStateTree: state.bigTree } }
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Space)
----------
//Oak.js
export default function Oak (inputState = null) {
 dosome 3D dance 
 return bigStateTree
}
```

using ReactJS and Redux on the ctrl panel (Space.js), some 3d on canvas (Oak.js).
The question is:
I wish to get data from the Oak.js from the return value then rerender (call the Newstate = Oak(oldState) again) the 3d base in the state, it is the loop when 3d change state changes when state change 3d changes, no click no change.

base on recommendations from StackOverflow [NEVER mutate this.state directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528444/react-can-you-use-setstate-with-existing-state-object)

I have no idea what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in the constructor you need to set the initial state. You do this as follows, where yourProperty is the key you want and defaultValue is a value of you choosing:

```
this.state = { yourProperty: defaultValue }
```

Then in componentWillMount():

```
this.setState({ yourProperty: Oak(this.state.yourProperty) })
```

and finally to access the state in the render() method:

```
return (
    <div>{this.state.yourProperty}</div>
    );
```

The only time you can assign a value to this.state without the setState method is in the constructor.  Also note you can't change state in the render() method.

Reading up on the React Component Lifecycle would be useful.

Comment: Thank you @Andre, I did read the ReactJs doc.  currently, I using the reducer, to dispatch store. with the new state created by calling ( Newstate = Oak(oldState) ), so this function will call again. then rerender again. Is that possible, or I  am on the wrong track by calling a function reproducing the state.

Comment: I tend to limit the use of redux to where it makes sense. You need to ask yourself whether you are dealing with something that should be local state or whether it should be shared amongst components.

Comment: all components need to share with the Store, only a few components,  apart from the canvas

Comment: What is responsible for updating the state and dispatching. Your components should receive the updated redux state via the this.props, due to mapStateToProps

Comment: using it to keeping the Canvas latest Data and updating the DB

Comment: at the end, I use the localstorage solutions for keeping the data, may be I use it ( UI state ) the wrong way